# SignalR and Web API communication

Tags: signalr, webapi

In one server, I have 2 web applications. One of them is a Web API, and the other one is SignalR. Both apps are hosted in IIS, under 2 different application pulls.

What is the best way to communicate between those 2 web applications? Is using either SignalR, or REST calls viable, for example?

Comment: We had a similar situation at my old workplace. We went with signalR on the API and REST for the application. I'd say it depends on your workload. How many calls do you roughly expect / day?

Comment: a lot of message per day , i dont have a number but its a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use several way;

1) A message queue system would work. Your server is IIS, you can use **MSMQ**.

2) Alternate to MSMQ, you can use **RabbitMQ**.

3) As you mentioned, you can use **HTTP** calls.

4) You have already a **SignalR**. So you can use it for communication. Write a Hub that the servers join to hub.

Options are depends on your requirement. Backend servers, mostly, communicate with a message queue system. HTTP calls are also acceptable.

The biggest difference between HTTP and a message queue is async calls. For example, When a HTTP call trying to reach an endpoint, it waits for a response and if the server is down, you have to try again until server up. On the other hand, a message queue system uses a queue. Just fire and forget the data. Other side of the connection can get the data whenever the server is ready.

SignalR is too risky for this job.